# How to store the results of a for-loop in R when the result is a vector

Tags: r, string, for-loop, vector

When looping over a function that produces a vector, I simply want to be able to store the resulting vectors as one long vector.

This does not work:

```
n_total <- 5
grps <- 2
start_s <- 0.7
start_v <- 0.8
Alpha <- 0.9

cols <- vector()
for(i in seq(grps)){
  if(i > 1){
    start_s <- start_s-0.1
    start_v <- start_v-0.1
  }
  cols[i] <- rainbow(n_total, start_s, start_v, alpha = Alpha)
}
```

So the result stored in `cols` should be:

`[1] "#B34747E6" "#9DB347E6" "#47B372E6" "#4772B3E6" "#9D47B3E6" "#994D4DE6" "#8A994DE6" "#4D996BE6" "#4D6B99E6" "#8A4D99E6"`

i.e. a 1x10 vector of strings.

Answer (score 1):

In the OP's, post, the 'cols' is initialized with a `length` 0.  One option here would to be append the vector while assigning to it in each iteration

```
cols <- vector()
for(i in seq(grps)){
if(i > 1){
 start_s <- start_s-0.1
  start_v <- start_v-0.1
  }
  cols<- c(cols, rainbow(n_total, start_s, start_v, alpha = Alpha))
}


cols
#[1] "#CC3D3DE6" "#AFCC3DE6" "#3DCC76E6" "#3D76CCE6" "#AF3DCCE6" "#B34747E6" "#9DB347E6" "#47B372E6"
#[9] "#4772B3E6" "#9D47B3E6"
```

---

If the OP wanted to run not with a fixed 0.1 to subtract

```
cols <- vector()
i1 <- seq(0, by = 0.1, length.out = grps)
for(i in seq_len(grps)) {
   if(i > 1){
    start_s <- start_s-i1[i]
     start_v <- start_v-i1[i]
     }  
     cols<- c(cols, rainbow(n_total, start_s, start_v, alpha = Alpha))
  }



cols
#[1] "#B34747E6" "#9DB347E6" "#47B372E6" "#4772B3E6" "#9D47B3E6" "#994D4DE6" "#8A994DE6" "#4D996BE6"
#[9] "#4D6B99E6" "#8A4D99E6"
```

---

Instead, it would be more efficient to initialize with a pre-determined length and then do the index assignment.  But, here, there are some things uncertain i.e. it is doing an `if` check and only if that is TRUE, then it is doing the assignment

```
cols <- character(10)
```

NOTE: OP's asked for a `for` loop here.  In `R`, there are better ways to deal with it instead of `for` loop

Comment: I concur with "NOTE: OP's asked for a for loop here", however, I think that it is wrong from an educational perspective to provide exactly what the OP requested, without at least mentioning that it is not the best practice to accomplish it with a `for` loop. Perhaps you should mention this in the solution (or even provide the alternative alongside) in order to make it more complete.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mapply` here :

```
n_total <- 5
grps <- 2
start_s <- 0.7
start_v <- 0.8
Alpha <- 0.9


inds <- seq(0, by = 0.1, length.out = grps)
c(mapply(function(x, y) rainbow(n_total, x, y, alpha = Alpha), 
         start_s - inds, start_v - inds))

#[1] "#B34747E6" "#9DB347E6" "#47B372E6" "#4772B3E6" "#9D47B3E6" 
#    "#994D4DE6" "#8A994DE6" "#4D996BE6" "#4D6B99E6" "#8A4D99E6"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this isn't what you were expecting (having placed the for-loop tag), but you should refrain from using R for loops when you can. Instead get used to using vectorized operations for iterations. They are much more efficient and produce a more readable code. One option is using `mapply` here is another approach using `map` (the `purrr` package).

The `tibble` function creates the bases for the iteration (the iterator if you will).

The combination of `mutate` and `map` is what actually runs the `rainbow` function and preserves its results in the `tibble`.

The results are provided as a list within a list (a character vector column inside the tibble), so `unnest` is used to extract them back to a regular vector.

Eventually, to get it as a simple vector you can use `answer_tib$rainbow_val`.

Please note that the output you provided in the question is inconsistent with the output you should get. It's unclear why maybe you meant to use different values for `start_s` and `start_v`?

```r
library(tidyverse)

n_total <- 5
set_alpha <- 0.9
start_s <- 0.7
start_v <- 0.8

answer_tib <- tibble(run_index = seq(0, 0.1, by = 0.1)) %>% 
  mutate(rainbow_val = map(run_index, ~{
    rainbow(n = n_total, start_s - .x, start_v - .x, alpha = set_alpha)
  })) %>% 
  unnest(rainbow_val)

answer_tib$rainbow_val
#>  [1] "#CC3D3DE6" "#AFCC3DE6" "#3DCC76E6" "#3D76CCE6" "#AF3DCCE6" "#B34747E6"
#>  [7] "#9DB347E6" "#47B372E6" "#4772B3E6" "#9D47B3E6"
```